# Skip java extension in XML, when it is not available

Tags: java, xslt, saxon

I have created Java extension

```
xmlns:convert="java:com.package.GreateClass"
```

This work, when *com.package.GreateClass* is in some classpath with XML processor. In other case I get compile error in extension run line. 
Can I run XSL transform and skip *com.package.GreateClass* running when it isn't in some classpath with xml processor?

P.S. I use Saxon 9.1 XML processor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
use-when="function-available('java:com.package.GreateClass')"
```

use-when does conditional compilation in XSLT, the code is ignored if the condition is false at compile time.